# Taking informations from another site

Tags: php

i am trying to get infos from another site.

```
<td>
    <?php
    $site=file_get_contents("$link");
    $price='#<div class="price_a">(.*?)<\/div>#si';
    preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);
    for ($a=0; $a<1; $a++){
        echo $pricelist[1][$a];
    }
    ?>
</td>

<td>
    <?php
    $site=file_get_contents("$link");
    $price='#<div class="price_a">(.*?)<\/div>#si';
    preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);
    for ($a=1; $a<2; $a++){
        echo $pricelist[1][$a];
    }
    ?>
</td>
```

But in the source code there are also tags like `<div class="price_m">` or `<div class="price_n">`

How can i take all tags from this site and use it in  tags?

Thanks...

Comment: and sorry about my english. i hope i can explain myself

Comment: What do you mean by How can i take all tags from this site and use it in tags?

Comment: regex isn't really the best way to parse HTML :S

Comment: like <div class="price_m"> , <div class="price_n"> , <div class="price_a">

Comment: regex isn't really the best way to parse HTML :S  - i am new at php. what do you prefer instead of regex? i will look it.

Comment: Here is a wonderful question for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags **tl; dr:** Use something like SimpleHTMLDom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood you properly, but why not just use a wildcard on the class name, too?

```
<td>
<?php
$site=file_get_contents("$link");
$price='#<div class="price_[a-z]">(.*?)<\/div>#si';
preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);
for ($a=0; $a<1; $a++){
echo $pricelist[1][$a];
}
?>
</td>

<td>
<?php
$site=file_get_contents("$link");
$price='#<div class="price_[a-z]">(.*?)<\/div>#si';
preg_match_all($price,$site,$pricelist);
for ($a=1; $a<2; $a++){
echo $pricelist[1][$a];
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

For parsing HTML string i think best is to use [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).
It has jQuery style selectors which are very easy to use.

```
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($link);

foreach($html->find('div.price_a') as $price_a) {
  // all div.price_a
}
foreach($html->find('div.price_m') as $price_m) {
  // all div.price_m
}
foreach($html->find('div.price_n') as $price_n) {
  // all div.price_n
}
```